# Integrating Jasper Reports from Jasper Report Server in web application

Tags: java, jsf, jasperserver

I am trying to display Jasper reports from Jasper Report Server on my JSF web application, but I am not able to find any documentation or resource that describe how to achieve it. I am currently using Jasper reports in my project, but I am planning to move the reports to Jasper Report Server for better performance and maintenance and access the reports from the Jasper report server using any adaptor or library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

I am answering to help anyone searching for similar question.

I am able to integrate JR Server using [jrs-rest-client](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jrs-rest-java-client#running-a-report).
Here is my sample code

```
RestClientConfiguration configuration = new RestClientConfiguration("http://localhost:8080/jasperserver");
JasperserverRestClient client = new JasperserverRestClient(configuration);
Session session = client.authenticate("user", "password");

OperationResult<InputStream> result = session
    .reportingService()
    .report("/E_Reports/myReport")
    .prepareForRun(ReportOutputFormat.PDF, 1)
    .parameter("param", "702558")
    .run();

InputStream report = result.getEntity();
```

**Solution 2:**

There is another solution. I find on this link.

https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/815042/run-report-using-restv2-and-java